# how to get the last insert id from a table in DB2 using nodejs and ibm_db package

Tags: node.js, db2

I would like to get back the primary key of the last inserted row in DB2 form node.js using ibm_db package. I tried using

```
select id from NEW TABLE (insert into (val1, val2, ...) values ('lorem', 'ipsum', ...))
```

and `.prepare(sql, callback)` to make DB call in node.js. The result in the callback doesn't contain any property or method to get the auto-generated key. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to fetch the data from result after execute as below:

```
  conn.prepare("select * from mytab1", function (err, stmt) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
      return conn.closeSync();
    }
    stmt.execute([], function(err, result) {
      if(err) console.log(err);
      else {
        data = result.fetchAllSync();
        console.log("Fetched Data = " );
        console.log(data);
        result.closeSync();
        conn.close(function () { console.log('done'); });
      }
    });
  });
```

Check the ibm_db/test/test-basic-test.js file for details. Thanks.